# AMP blocking the main thread

Tags: amp-html, pagespeed

I'm using AMP and Google PageSpeed Insights is suggesting to reduce third-party code and it includes AMP. Currently the score is around 77-82. I just want to make it stable, say 85, and this is the highest opportunity Google is suggesting.

[image: PageSpeed Insights]

Also, there's this 'Defer offscreen images' even though I'm using a valid `amp-img` tags. Aren't amp-img tags supposed to be always lazy loaded?

Comment: Is this page valid AMP? How are you loading the AMP runtime?

Comment: @fstanis I think it is. I have no error using the Chrome plugin.

Comment: I'm confused why you have Bootstrap CDN there in that case?

Comment: I am having this issue too where AMP is reported as blocking the main thread. Valid AMP page.  Did you ever solve the problem?